# Generating nested lists

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm pretty much new to typoscript. I know about wrapping but how do you generate well-formed nested lists?

Here is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
// Side menu with each li acting as a category
lib.subMenu.1 {
  NO.allWrap=<li class="category">|</li>

// (...)

lib.subMenu {
  2 < .1
  // LI placed just underneath and wrapped inside a UL.
  // Ideally the UL should be inside the LI described above.
  2.wrap = <li><ul class="items">|</ul></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `wrapItemAndSub` for wrapping items

```
lib.subMenu = HMENU
lib.submenu {
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
      wrap = <ul>|</ul>
      NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
   }

   2 < .1
   2.wrap = <ul class="level_2">|</ul>
}
```

Comment: Also see this anwser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401926/how-to-use-option-split-to-control-typo3-menu-properties/10409292#10409292