# Typo3 - Make a menu of pages child of Page with ID = X

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a number of pages inside a SysFolder with ID = 24.

How could I make with typoscript a TMENU with all the immediate children of this folder, so that if I add new pages later, they appear automatically in this menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this answer: [How to use option split to control typo3 menu properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401926/how-to-use-option-split-to-control-typo3-menu-properties/10409292#10409292)

Just change the `special.value` to the page id of your sysfolder.

Answer (score 0):

A CType sitemap can create a TMENU form all pages in a tree or folder.